# Android app signing: for an existing app with "OPT OUT", can I change it to [App signing by Google Play]

Tags: android, release-management, android-app-signing

1. As the title, we released an app but had selected the "OPT OUT" as the attached screenshot. Can we change it to [App signing by Google Play] as like clicking the [Continue] button?
   Because this app was released for a year, and got some users, we do not want to create another app to replace it and restart again.

[image: The screenshot when first app release]

2. It looks like we should go to [App signing] of the existing app to do the option [You've exported your app signing key](as the screenshot below).
   But when uploading the key store file used in Android Studio [Generate Signed APK], it appears error. In fact, we do not exactly understand the logic of key files. Any idea or experience is welcome.
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you still have a hold of your keystore (if you already have published an APK).

You need to upload an APK first, then go to the "App Signing" menu on the left-hand side bar and follow the instructions, and you will be able to enroll in App Signing by Play there.

Alternatively, delete the app and recreate it. Faster, but not always an option :)

Comment: thanks for the reply! But the way to enroll in App Signing for an existing app, which was OPT OUT, is just still for OPT OUT. It's not as the screenshot, to "permanently enroll your app into app signing by Google Play".

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "The way to enroll for an existing app, which was OPT OUT, is just still for OPT OUT".

When you enroll through the "App Signing" menu, you'll end up in the same place as if you had clicked on the "Continue" button on your screenshot.

Comment: So, do you have any idea about how to choose the options , when enter App Signing for an existing app, and upload what [App Signing Private Key]?
           
-You've exported your app signing key       
-You haven’t exported your app signing key
-You don't store your app signing key in a Java keystore
-Optional: Enhanced security for your app signing key

Comment: Hi! Pierre, anyway, I also email to ask Google and Google has a reply to me saying that "Please note that if you mistakenly opt-out of app signing and publish the app, there isn't a way to opt back in.". It's confusing. any comment?

Comment: They might have misunderstood what you asked for. Select the option "You haven't exported your app signing key", and also follow the optional enhanced security step.

Comment: Thanks! it works to select the option "You haven't exported your app signing key".